# TypeError: Expecting a string- or bytes-formatted key when using Flask-JWT

Tags: python, flask, jwt, flask-jwt

I have a question about flask python.
I tried learning how to build a web using flask, and there is some error. In this case I am using mongoengine as database and JWT(Json Web Token) and the alert error is like this: "TypeError: Expecting a string- or bytes-formatted key"

```
192.168.100.26 - - [22/Nov/2016 22:50:08] "POST /auth HTTP/1.1" 500 -
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/def/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2000, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/def/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1991, in wsgi_app
    response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))
  File "/home/def/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1567, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/def/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1988, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/home/def/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1641, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/home/def/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1544, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/def/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1639, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/home/def/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1625, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/home/def/pr/flask/flask_deeper/test/routes/auth.py", line 26, in auth
    access_token = _jwt.jwt_encode_callback(identity)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask_jwt/__init__.py", line 70, in _default_jwt_encode_handler
    return jwt.encode(payload, secret, algorithm=algorithm, headers=headers)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jwt/api_jwt.py", line 56, in encode
    json_payload, key, algorithm, headers, json_encoder
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jwt/api_jws.py", line 98, in encode
    key = alg_obj.prepare_key(key)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jwt/algorithms.py", line 116, in prepare_key
    raise TypeError('Expecting a string- or bytes-formatted key.')
TypeError: Expecting a string- or bytes-formatted key.
```

I thought the error was at this.

**models/user.py**

```
@staticmethod
def jwt_handler(token):
    if not User.objects(token=token):
        raise JWTError("Bad bad bad bad")

    secret = str(current_app.config["JWT_SECRET_KEY"])
    algorithm = str(current_app.config["JWT_ALGORITHM"])
    options = {
        'verify_' + claim: True
        for claim in verify_claims
    }

    options.update({
        'require_' + claim: True
        for claim in required_claims
    })

    decode = jwt.decode(token, secret, options=options, algorithms=[algorithm])
    return decode

@staticmethod
def authenticate(username, password):
    user = User.objects(username=username)
    if len(user) == 0:
        return None
    user = user[0]
    user["id"] = str(user["id"])

    if crypt.verify(password, user.password):
        return user

    return user
```

**routes/user.py**

```
def auth():
    username = request.form.get("username")
    password = request.form.get("password")

    if not username:
        raise BadRequest("Userna doesn't exists")

    user = user_ctrl.read(username)

    identity = _jwt.authentication_callback(username, password)

    if identity:
        access_token = _jwt.jwt_encode_callback(identity)
        identity.update(push__token=access.decode("utf8"))
        return _jwt.auth_response_callback(access_token, identity)
    else:
        raise JWTError("Bad bad bad very bad")
```

**config.py**

```
import os
from test.models import db

class Config(object):

    db_name = os.getenv('MONGODB_NAME', 'third')
    db_host = os.getenv('MONGODB_HOST', '127.0.0.1')
    db_port  = os.getenv('MONGODB_PORT', '5000')

    JWT_SECRET_KEY = 'test123'
    JWT_ALGORITHM = 'SH256'
    JWT_AUTH_ENDPOINT = 'jwt'
    JWT_AUTH_USERNAME_KEY = 'username'
    JWT_AUTH_PASSWORD_KEY = 'password'
```

**http.py**

```
import logging.config
import jwt
from flask_jwt import JWT
from flask import Flask

from test import routes
from test.models import db, User

_jwt = JWT(authentication_handler=User.authenticate, identity_handler=User.identity)
_jwt.jwt_decode_callback=User.jwt_handler

def create_app(config):
    app = Flask(__name__.split(',')[0])

    app.register_blueprint(routes.user.bp)
    app.register_blueprint(routes.auth.bp)

    db.init_app(app)

    _jwt.init_app(app)

    return app
```

Comment: The traceback says the error is at `File "/home/def/pr/flask/flask_deeper/test/routes/auth.py", line 26` Can you post the code present there?

Comment: this the code on line 26.

access_token = _jwt.jwt_encode_callback(identity)

Comment: No I meant the whole code block

Comment: <code>@bp.route("/auth", methods=["POST"])
def auth():
 username = request.form.get("username")
 password = request.form.get("password")

 if not username:
  raise BadRequest("Userna doesn't exists")

 user = user_ctrl.read(username)

 identity = _jwt.authentication_callback(username, password)

 if identity:
  access_token = _jwt.jwt_encode_callback(identity)
#  identity.update(push__token=access.decode("utf8"))
  return _jwt.auth_response_callback(access_token, identity)
 else:
  raise JWTError("Bad bad bad very bad"
</code>

Comment: You can "edit" your question and add the code block there (The link to edit is at the end of the question to the left hand side). It is difficult to understand code pasted in comments.

Comment: Also post the config of your app (By editing the question)

Comment: @RedBaron i edited my question

Comment: Well, it looks like your configured authentication callback is not sending the correct expected `identity`. I am not familiar with JWT but I guess you may be returning an object when you should return a string there.

Comment: Im sorry, i forgot to tell you about the config.py is connected with http.py, i thought the sender object in http.py. @RedBaron

Comment: Can you also post the models.user.py:User.authenticate method?

Comment: Done, i add the authenticate on models.py @RedBaron

Comment: Well it is really difficult for me to tell what is wrong. If I hazard a guess, maybe you have not initialized your config with something like `app.config.from_object`, so `app.config["JWT_SECRET_KEY"]` returns None. Otherwise, I guess you should wait till someone with more experience in Flask and JWT takes a look at this.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your replay. @RedBaron

Comment: Mr.@RedBaron my code it's working, thank you for your help. you right, i forgot to call config.py on http.py. this is really really help 'app.config.from_object'. thank you so much.

Comment: Well glad to help. I'll post that as an answer (for reps :D)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have defined the configuration is `config.py` but have not added the configuration object to your flask app. Therefore, keys such as `JWT_SECRET_KEY` are not in your app config.

Flask-JWT's [default_handler](https://github.com/mattupstate/flask-jwt/blob/master/flask_jwt/__init__.py#L74) expects those values (Copied in case source changes)

```
def _default_jwt_decode_handler(token):
    secret = current_app.config['JWT_SECRET_KEY']
    algorithm = current_app.config['JWT_ALGORITHM']
    leeway = current_app.config['JWT_LEEWAY']
```

In your case as that is not set, it returns `None` and trips the `algorithms.py` (which expects a string key).

Therefore, during your app initialization in http.py, you must add a call to `app.config.from_object`. Maybe something like this

```
def create_app(config):
    app = Flask(__name__.split(',')[0])

    # Edit the following to point it to your Config class
    app.config.from_object(config.Config)

    app.register_blueprint(routes.user.bp)
    app.register_blueprint(routes.auth.bp)

    db.init_app(app)

    _jwt.init_app(app)

    return app
```

On a side note, the name of `JWT_ALGORITHM` should be `HS256` rather than `SH256` (Although it doesn't matter as `HS256` is the default and will be chosen since `SH256` is not a valid algorithm)